# How to check is GPRS is available

Tags: iphone

Is there any way to check whether GPRS is available on the iPhone?
I've written code that checks whether WiFi is available, but I don't know how to do this for GPRS.

Comment: If it's indeed code you want help with, please post what you have started with, and make your question a little clearer to read.

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1021172/how-to-check-network-type-in-iphone-app and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/178636/way-to-discover-which-internet-connection-type-im-using-on-the-iphone

Answer (score 2):

I think you are getting confused with `whether wifi is available or not` and `GPRS is available or not`.

Wifi is avilable or not could mean that the code might check whether any wifi hot spots are available. but in the case of gprs it is different.

What you can do a send a request to a site and see if you get the response. If you get then they are connected to the internet (GPRS/3G or whatever)

BTW consider accepting few answers you have 17 questions and 0 acceptance rate.